# Where to enter logic form logic

Tags: javascript, yii

I have a form, in which there 2 text boxes representing Year of Birth and Age.

Business rules state:
1. If a year is entered, age is calculated, and set to read only
2. If a year does not exist, clear age, and allow it to be edited

So, if I enter the form, and input a year, age is calculated and set to read only. But if I clear the year, I want age to also clear and become editable.

In what function do I enter the check for when year is cleared? I tried putting in the afterrener, and initComponent, but that doesn't work

Comment: what approach did you use to to calculate age and set to read only? Did you use js or yii's functions? I think you can use onkeyup event of the age text box to re-enable editing.

Comment: I used the keyup listener function, and from there called a function - calcAge, which is located in the initComponent section.

Comment: Could you please include your code? I'll have a look and try to run it.